# Matplotlib and Pandas Plotting Score average for every year

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have pandas Dataframe that looks like this:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to scatter plot the average of each 'Score' for how each 'Publish Date' Value, which is [1...10]

I tried to use groupby, mean, etc. But for some reason, this is not working properly.

```
df.groupby(ds['Publish Date'].dt)["Score"].mean().plot(kind="line",rot=25)
```

I wish to have a scatter plot, with X as [1...10] and Y as the Score average.
I need to take every unique value from ds['Publish Date'], which is values between 1 to 10, and for each one of the, to get the average score. For example - for 10: 2.4, for 9: 4.7 and to have those stats in a scatter plot. Thank you!

Need some help, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use seaborn to plot it, it's very intuitive.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Publish_date"] = [random.randrange(0,11) for _ in range(20)]
df["Score"] = [random.randrange(0,60)/10 for _ in range(20)]

df_grouped_by_year = df.groupby(df['Publish_date']).mean()
sns.scatterplot(data = df_grouped_by_year)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45ILJ.png)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but It is not working for now. Can you please explain why you used random?

Comment: I used random to generate dataframe, all functionality is in last line.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I am not getting the average for every year. I need to take every unique value from ds['Publish Date'], which is values between 1 to 10, and for each one of the, to get the average score. For example - for 10: 2.4, for 9: 4.7 and to have those stats in a scatter plot. Thank you!

Comment: I edited my post, it should work now